# How to convert Lat, Lon, Alt to ECEF and EPSG 4979?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, gdal-translate, cesium

I am programmatically generating data to use in [Cesium's 3D Tile System](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles/tree/master/specification). The data I have is in `(Latitude, Longitude, Altitude)` format. To display the data in Cesium, I have to first define a region to render the data in, and for that I am trying to use a [region](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles/tree/master/specification#region). However, I do not understand what the values they use to define their North, East, West, South. I try to use the following line of code to transform my data, which is in EPSG 4326, to EPSG 4979, but it spits out the same values:

```
> gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4979
-134 47
-134 47
```

I am using Python's GDAL bindings, and I need to do two things:

1. Convert (LAT,LON,ALT) to Cesium's ECEF co-ordinate system (X,Y,Z) to display the objects at the right position.
2. Convert the edges of my dataset to a region that Cesium's tileset.json will understand. Here's my dataset format:

GDAL_INFO:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",38.5],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",38.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",38.5],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",262.5],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Metre",1]]
Origin = (-2699020.142521935515106,1588193.847443337785080)
Pixel Size = (3000.000000000000000,-3000.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-2699020.143, 1588193.847) (134d 7'17.14"W, 47d50'44.64"N)
Lower Left  (-2699020.143,-1588806.153) (122d43'44.80"W, 21d 7'19.89"N)
Upper Right ( 2697979.857, 1588193.847) ( 60d53'28.48"W, 47d50'57.51"N)
Lower Right ( 2697979.857,-1588806.153) ( 72d16'48.48"W, 21d 7'28.62"N)
Center      (    -520.143,    -306.153) ( 97d30'21.52"W, 38d29'50.09"N)
```

How do I go about achieving this?

---

Just to add some more information, my source dataset coverts CONUS. And my playing around with the values, this is an approximate tileset "region" that covers that area:

[image]

```
"region": [
        -2.2197004795898053,
    0.488582109,
    -1.2196595204101946,
    0.7988897891,
    0,
    300000
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am probably confused. Is the one you have posted output of GDAL_INFO, the same as the one you put into gdal_transform function? Looks like it is on projected CRS , not geographic.

Comment: No, the inputs on the `gdaltranform` are the latitude, longitude I got from converting the source data to `(LAT, LON, HEIGHT)` in my Python code. If there is a way to directly transform my source data to ECEF and EPSG4979, I'd love to know. I am converting it to LAT, LON, HEIGHT because I figured that would make it easier for me to get an answer.

Comment: Try 4978 instead. It's geodetic CRS (geocentric). 4979 is geodetic CRS (3D geographic) AKA latitude, longitude, ellipsoidal height. Which is something else to deal with. Your altitude may be geoidal/gravity-related and off up to 100 m compared to ellipsoidal heights which is what you should use to convert to geocentric coordinates.

Comment: In what format do you have the input data? if you just want to define a region, get the bounding box coordinates and transform them with shapely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943093/library-to-perform-coordinate-system-transformations/27943394#27943394